# How to append a value to a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I guess this is a bit of a noob question but I haven't seen this question asked so I don't know if it is possible. I would like to construct a MySQL query where I can append a value to the result. What I mean by way of an example:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title
FROM program p
INNER JOIN node n ON p.nid = n.nid ORDER BY node_title
```

So this query will return a result and now I would like to either append or prepend an arbitrary value to the result to get the following:

```
arbitrary_value
result1
result2
result3
etc...
```

So is there some MySQL statement that wraps this query to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can accomplish that using the UNION operator:

```
SELECT 'arbitrary_value' as node_title
UNION ALL
(SELECT n.title AS node_title
  FROM program p
  INNER JOIN node n ON p.nid = n.nid ORDER BY node_title)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I suspected there might be something but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use UNION syntax

```
SELECT arbitrary_value AS node_title

UNION ALL

SELECT node.title
FROM program p
INNER JOIN node n ON p.nid = n.nid 

ORDER BY node_title
```

Please note that the column alias has to go in the first SELECT.